# Is it possible to change newline constant for $stderr in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, newline, stderr

Is it possible to change all newline printed on `$stderr.puts` or `$stderr.print` into some other characters?

for example, changing into `:.`:

```
$stderr.print "123.45\n\n"
=> 123.45 :. :.
$stderr.puts 'yay'
=> yay :.
```

If it's possible, how?

Comment: What is the purpose of this need?

Comment: to make all errors' newline from gems (from a simple CGI script) into `<br/>`

Comment: @Kokizzu if you want to show the error log in a web browser, wrap it in a `<pre>` tag.

Comment: yes, but there are some case that the error shows up even before `<pre>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Stefan wrote in the comment, probably you should use an HTML `<pre>` tag instead, or CSS `white-space: pre` directive on a non-pre element. Anyway:

`$stderr.print`:

```
def $stderr.print(*args)
  super *args.map { |v| v.to_s.gsub("\n", "<br>") }
end
$stderr.print "ciao\n" #=> nil
ciao<br>
```

`$stderr.puts`:

```
def $stderr.puts(*args)
  print *args.map { |v| v.to_s + "\n" }
end
$stderr.puts "ciao" #=> nil
ciao<br>
```